# Issue with Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am working on my first android app and one issue that I have not been able to find the solution is with the relative layout and footer bar.

I have set up a relative layout with a button bar at the bottom.  It works find if there is enough content in the other linear layout; however, when there is not enough content to fill out the page, the content is aligned at the bottom on top of the button bar.  I would like it to be aligned at the top with the button bar remaining on the bottom.  I have tried every align top option I can find and setting the content height to fill_parent/match_parent, but all of those cause the items inside of the linear layout to disappear.

How can I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ViewPost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#c9c9c9" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/content_new_event"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:text="@string/BtnComment"
        android:textColor="#797979"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMeToo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/social_add_group"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:text="@string/BtnMeToo"
        android:textColor="#797979"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFlag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:text="@string/BtnFlag"
        android:textColor="#797979"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/social_share"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:text="@string/BtnShare"
        android:textColor="#797979"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticket_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ticket_owner_image2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="#797979"
        android:contentDescription="@string/StdImageDesc"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/picture" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ticket_owner_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:textColor="#595959"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ticket_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:textColor="#595959"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ticket_create_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:textColor="#595959"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ticket_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:textColor="#595959"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/commentlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following and let me know if this what you want to achieve:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ViewPost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#c9c9c9" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/commentlist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnComment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dummy_heyzooka_icon_blue"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="8dip"
                android:paddingRight="8dip"
                android:paddingTop="2dip"
                android:text="aa"
                android:textColor="#797979"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMeToo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dummy_heyzooka_icon_blue"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="8dip"
                android:paddingRight="8dip"
                android:paddingTop="2dip"
                android:text="dd"
                android:textColor="#797979"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFlag"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dummy_heyzooka_icon_blue"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="8dip"
                android:paddingRight="8dip"
                android:paddingTop="2dip"
                android:text="ff"
                android:textColor="#797979"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnShare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dummy_heyzooka_icon_blue"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="8dip"
                android:paddingRight="8dip"
                android:paddingTop="2dip"
                android:text="ff"
                android:textColor="#797979"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ticket_id"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ticket_owner_image2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:background="#797979"
                    android:contentDescription="ada"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/dummy_heyzooka_icon_blue" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ticket_owner_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:textColor="#595959"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ticket_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:textColor="#595959"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ticket_create_date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:textColor="#595959"
                        android:textSize="10sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ticket_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip"
                    android:textColor="#595959"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi First of all when your working with relative layout be caution because if you change an alignment or any modifications on that layout it will disappear (or) it may change the alignment , So don't worry undo your layout u can come back to your previous alignment now you can modify one by one item in the layout.